# How to check for inequality between fields in same document in Azure Cognitive search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have an index set up in Azure cognitive search that has two string fields (hash1 & hash2) containing separate hashes. We would like to query the index for documents where the two hashes within a document aren't equal.

I tried applying the filter: `$filter=hash1 ne hash2`, expecting the query to return all documents with mismatched hashes. Instead, I was greeted with the following error message:

```
"Invalid expression: Comparison must be between a field, range variable or function call and a literal value.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
```

From what I can gather there seems to be some kind of limitation preventing comparisons between fields. Would it be possible to perform this type of query in Azure cognitive search using a different technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use content enrichment in this case. Even if comparing two hashes with a query was supported, it would be inefficient compared to pre-calculating the value using a content enrichment technique.

1. Introduce a new boolean property called something like HasEqualHashes
2. Populate that property with an appropriate boolean value
3. Use a $filter to filter your content as you wish

   search=whatever&$filter=HasEqualHashes

Note that two different scenarios determine how you can enrich your content.

CONTENT SUBMITTED VIA SDK

When you use the SDK to submit content, you can enrich your items any way you want using regular code. Populating your HasEqualHashes property is a trivial one-liner in C#.

CONTENT SUBMITTED USING BUILT-IN INDEXERS

If you use one of the built-in indexers, you have to learn and understand the concept of skillsets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-working-with-skillsets

[image: Conceptual drawing of skillsets from microsoft.com]

Comment: We update the different hash fields on separate occasions using the C# SDK. E.g. in function1 we update hash1, and in function2 we update hash2. Would it be possible to populate the HasEqualHashes without first reading the document?

Comment: If you want to maintain the HasEqualHashes property using the C# SDK, you must read the document in function2 to get the latest hash1 value. Unless function2 has some other way of knowing what hash1 is (via a cache or lookup table). However, nothing stops you from building a custom skillset that maintains HasEqualHashes whenever the item is updated. Using a skillset will also be process-secure in your case. If you had to rely on reading the document before updating, there is a risk that the item changed after you read it and before you wrote to it again.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. In our case, all the content in this index is pushed via the C# SDK. In other words, we don't use an indexer to populate any of the data. Looking at the link on skillsets you provided, it looks like a skillset requires an indexer, and an indexer requires a data source. Since we have neither, would using a skillset still be possible?

Comment: You are correct. I removed my comment claiming that skillsets could be used when you submit content via the C# SDK. Choosing to submit content via the C# SDK vs. using a built-in indexer is fundamentally different. I always prefer to use the C# SDK because it gives me the most flexibility for content enrichment, which we use heavily. "Coding" in JSON without a debugger feels clumsy compared to C#. 

In your case, you should read the hash1 value when you write hash2. And then maintain the HasEqualHashes property accordingly.